# reflex test in excel - trouble running auto code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running an visual field test where I see # correct cell selections at different levels of gray. The code works as intended with the exception of the auto-running/refresh. the code seems to gradually unwind the stack and not refresh at the predetermined interval.

Code:

```
Public response As Boolean
Public r As Integer
Public c As Integer
Public count As Integer


Sub reflex()
Dim start As Range

Set start = Range("A1")


If response = True Then
    If ActiveCell <> start.Offset(r, c) Then
        count = count + 1
        Range("A1:AZ100").ClearFormats
        start.Activate
        Beep
        response = False
    Else
        Range("A1:AZ100").ClearFormats
        start.Activate
        response = False
    End If
Else
    If WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 100) / 100 > 0.2 Then
        r = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 57)
        c = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 32)
        start.Offset(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(245, 245, 245)
        response = True
    End If
End If


start.Value = Now
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("reflex").Calculate 'This is where the problem is

End Sub
```

The expected result is that every 5 sec, the code runs, determines the condition correct condition and the proceeds to run. It does this when I run the code discretely 4-5 times. The issue is when I try to automate it in the private sub worksheet_calculate() subroutine.

Comment: Can you include how you call it in `Worksheet_Calculate`? That is important, since it seems like your calling `Calculate` within a calculate event.

Comment: All of your operations working on the `ActiveSheet`, but at the end you are specifically invoking `Calculate` on the `"reflex"` worksheet. Is the `ActiveSheet` = `"reflex"` ?

Comment: You might want to try and use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event, rather than the `Worksheet_Calculate` event.